# SAS EG (SQL) mutliple criteria lookup

Tags: sql, join, sas, lookup

I currently have two tables. The first one has a bunch of information. The relevant information is the maj_cvg_code which has a value of 'opv', 'pro', 'ipa' and a maj_diag_code which is some number. When you combine both of these pieces of information you will get an actual name for each row.

The second table has the maj_cvg_code and maj_diag_code and the name. How do I get SAS/SQL to print the name of the category on each row?

Comment: Please add to your question to show samples of the data you have, the desired output, and what code you have tried.

Comment: You can join on more than one field in a SQL join. If you need help, post sample data, expected output and what you've tried so far.